# Eclipse, android developer tools doesn't start

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I've reinstall Eclipse with adt plugins, but when I start it doesn't launch the developers tools.
The first windows that appaers is the eclipse juno and when the loading is finish I have not all the tools for android.

How can I reinstall correctly all?

OS: Windows 7

[image]

If you see the picture, the icon on the left does't appaer and not are all the tools.

Comment: When you go to Window drop-down menu in Eclipse, can you see Android related stuff at the bottom of that menu? Just to be sure...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html -> VIEW ALL DOWNLOADS AND SIZES. Download and replace previous sdk tools, also check in eclipse settings if path to sdk tools is set correctly

Comment: Michal: when I go in the menu I don't see Android related stuff

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, menu Help > Install new software > Work with  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ > Check Developer Tools and install.

Comment: When select to install the developer tools the operation cannot be completed. It say that the tools are installed, but my Eclipse does't work good.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the whole Eclipse ADT bundle in one go from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=adt)
This comes set up with everything and you can just start your work.

Comment: Is this that I have installed.

Answer (score 0):

In the Quick search try to type java then you are able to see the sdk manager icon and the avd icon on the menu.....

Answer (score 0):

*Check what you really installed by going to -*

*`Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Installed Software`.*

[image]

If you see no ADT in the list, it wasn't installed and you need to install.

The step-by-step-guide on [installing-the-android-sdk-with-adt-plugin-on-eclipse-juno](http://www.duckout.de/eclipse/installing-the-android-sdk-with-adt-plugin-on-eclipse-juno/).

Comment: Yes, they are the adt plugins.